# можно ли этот код оптимизировать(сократить и улучшить)?

Tags: javascript

код проверяет на совпадение в массиве введенного числа и возвращает true/false, число может начинаться как с 1 так и с 0 и содержать пробелы

код рабочий просто интересно то что я написал можно ли оптимизировать

```
let arr1 = ['043','099','011']
let num = '  099        '

let retBool = (arr,num) =>{
    let oneItem;
    for(let item = 0; item< arr.length; item++) {
        oneItem = num.replace(/\s/g,'')
        if(oneItem.length < 4 
           && (oneItem.startsWith('0') || oneItem.startsWith('1')) 
           && (oneItem === arr[item] || oneItem === arr[item].replace(/^\d/,'1'))){
           return true
         }else{
            continue
          }
      }
    return false
}
let x = retBool(arr1,num)
console.log(x);
```

Comment: oneItem = num.replace(/\s/g,'') можно вынести за цикл

Comment: `oneItem.length < 4 
           && (oneItem.startsWith('0') || oneItem.startsWith('1')` можно выкинуть

Comment: "Экономия на спичках", но можно так же arr.length вынести из цикла )

Comment: `console.log( arr1.includes( num.trim().replace(/^1/, "0") ) );` ?

Comment: @splash58 ты почти прав просто надо отделить эту проверку а не убрать чтобы цикл прервался

Comment: зачем? достаточно сравнения с элементами массива

Comment: @splash58 если число будет больше или не начнется с 1/0 можно пропустить пробежку по массиву и вернуть false

Comment: если оно будет больше, оно не совпадет ни с числом из массива, ни с числом с замененым 0 на 1

Comment: @splash58 чтобы проверить совпадет или нет надо по массиву пробежатся и сравнить а так не нужно этокая оптимизация(правда не знаю насколько) может массив из 100000 строк

Comment: я там  ответе написал достаточные условия. остальное, может и надо, если реальная задача требует

Comment: @splash58 решение не рабочее

Comment: @Yaant а проверка на 1 или 0 в num?

Comment: А что должна делать эта проверка? В смысле для num = '43' должно вернуться false? Из формулировки вопроса это совсем не очевидно.

Comment: @Yaant возвращает совпадение по массиву еще число может начинаться с 1 и это тоже проверяется с массивом заменяя там 0 на 1 глянь ответ Optimusa думаю самое лучшее решение

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME добавь как ответ галочку поставлю

Comment: болшое спасибо всем

Comment: @Leonid что за два знака !!? это же тоже самое что без них или я не прав?

Comment: @Leonid перевод к логическому типу?

Comment: @Leonid код не совсем рабочий но спасибо за подсказку к переводу к логическому типу

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME еще раз спасибо

Comment: @Armen, исправил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [Array.prototype.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

```js
let arr = ['043', '099', '011'];

console.log( includes(arr, '  099 ') ); // true
console.log( includes(arr, ' 199  ') ); // true
console.log( includes(arr, '0 99  ') ); // false
// *trim убирает пробелы только справа и слева. Внутренние не трогает.

function includes(arr, num) {
  num = num.trim().replace(/^1/, "0");
  return arr.includes(num);
}
```

2. Ну почти то же самое делается обычным перебором. Просто хорошо бы заранее обработать полученную строку и отправить в цикл на проверку строго то, что должно совпасть ( везде на проверку идет уже строка "099" )

```js
let arr = ['043', '099', '011', '177'];

console.log( includes(arr, '  099 ') ); // true
console.log( includes(arr, ' 199  ') ); // true
console.log( includes(arr, '0 9 9 ') ); // true
console.log( includes(arr, ' 077  ') ); // false (!)

function includes(arr, str) {
  str = str.replace(/\s/g, "").replace(/^1/, "0");
  
  for( let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
    if( arr[i] === str ) return true;
  }
  
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
let arr1 = ['043','099','011'];
let num = '  099        ';


let n = num.replace(/\s/g,'');    
let x = arr1.some(i => n === i || n === i.replace(/^\d/,'1'));

console.log(x);
```

Comment: если заменить на some, то !! не нужен

Comment: @Grundy, спасибо. Искал сегодня эту функцию перебора массива с условием. Давно не работал с JS. Помню, что что-то должно быть...